# Canada Post module for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, shipping-methods

Is there any shipping integration for Canada Post and Magento 2?

I see a few Canada Post modules for 1.x but they don't seem to be updated for 2.x.

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Comment: https://store.webkul.com/Marketplace-Canada-Post-Shipping-For-Magento2.html